# How to use Https:// base webservice in J2ME

Tags: java-me

I want to use **https://** based webservice so how can use that webservice in my project.Is there any sample code how to use **https://** webservice  and what is required **(e.g certificate,siging process)**  for to use that webservice in **J2ME**.please give me answer as soon as possible

Thanks in Advance.